# MapFragment cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: android, google-maps

While running my application(GoogleMaps) getting Android Library Projects cannot be launched? How can I resolve this one ?

My code is :

```
mMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

It gives error `MapFragment cannot be resolved as a type`

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import a google-play-services_lib from your android sdk to your current eclipse

path of the lib is in

```
adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

step to be followed

```
*In the Package Explorer, right-click the library project and select Properties.
*In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
*Select the "google-play-services_lib" checkbox and click Apply.
*Click OK to close the Properties window.
```

Then the map will be working fine